# diff two batches of files

Tags: bash, diff

I would like to diff two batches of files. If I simply put them in two different directories and diff by directory, the comparisons will be alphabetical which I do not want.

Another approach would be to list files in text1.txt and list files in text2.txt:

text1:

```
a1
b1
c1
```

text2:

```
c2
a2
b2
```

How can I approach this such that my loop will be:

```
diff a1 c2
diff b1 a2
diff b2 c1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `paste` to join the two files, then a bash loop to process.

```
paste text1 text2 | while read file1 file2; do diff "$file1" "$file2"; done
```

Comment: very nice, and it's a one liner. do you happen to know how to include the file names being diffed? that would be perfect

Comment: @Paolo I'm not sure exactly what you're asking for.  You could put a `echo "DIFF: $file1, $file2";` before the `diff` command to indicate the start of the diff for a set of files.

Comment: I wanted to print the file names being diff. This is what I was looking for: paste text1 text2 | while read file1 file2; do  diff --brief "$file1" "$file2" ; diff -y --suppress-common-lines $file1 $file2; done

Answer (score 2):

In bash, you can use the `-u` flag on read to read from a different fd. This allows you to read from two files in parallel:

```
while read -r -u3 file1 && read -r -u4 file2; do
  diff "$file1" "$file2"
done 3<file1.txt 4<file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution :

```
#!/bin/bash

file1="..."
file2="..."

getSize(){
    wc -l "$1"|cut -d " " -f1
}

getValueFromLineNumber(){
    sed -n "$1p" "$2"
}

diffFromLineNumber(){
    f1=$(getValueFromLineNumber "$1" "$file1")
    f2=$(getValueFromLineNumber "$1" "$file2")
    diff "$f1" "$f2"
}

# get min size
[[ $(getSize "$file1") -le $(getSize "$file2") ]] && min=$s1 || min=$s2

for (( i=1 ; i <= "$min" ; i++)); do
    diffFromLineNumber "$i"
done
```

This solution takes care of the case where the two files don't have the same number of lines.